# CountDown timer set text view - android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, handler, runnable, countdowntimer

I have a recycler view that consists of multiple count down timers per row.
Now, I have managed to get the text view updated according to the count down timer, but when the time ends, I want to change the text view to display "Time is over" instead of counting.

I have a custom view holder object that holds a reference to a Model object.
Now, I have a runnable

object that is responsible for counting the time, and I have a handler that runs the runnable every 500 millis.

Now, the count down timers are working very good but when the time ends, it simply shows me "00:00" instead of displaying a meesage "Time is over".

Here is my array adapter code. Inside it lies the code for handling the count down timers:

```
package bikurim.silverfix.com.bikurim.adapters;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import bikurim.silverfix.com.bikurim.models.Family;
import bikurim.silverfix.com.bikurim.R;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.FamilyViewHolder> implements Filterable{

    private ArrayList<Family> families;
    private ArrayList<Family> dataSet;
    private ArrayList<FamilyViewHolder> holders;
    private static long currentMillis, timeLeft;
    private Timer tmr;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Runnable updateRemainingTimeRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (holders) {
                for (FamilyViewHolder holder : holders) {
                    if(!holder.family.isTimeLeft) {
                        currentMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        timeLeft = holder.family.time - currentMillis;
                        holder.family.time = currentMillis + timeLeft;
                        if(holder.family.time > currentMillis) {
                            holder.updateFormatTime(currentMillis);
                        } else {
                            holder.family.isTimeLeft = true;
                            holder.timeLeft.setText("הזמן נגמר");
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    private FamilyFilter filter;
    private boolean flagSearch;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<Family> families) {
        this.dataSet = families;
        this.families = families;
        holders = new ArrayList<FamilyViewHolder>();
        startUpdateTimer();
    }

    private void startUpdateTimer() {
        tmr = new Timer();
        tmr.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(updateRemainingTimeRunnable);
            }
        }, 500, 500);
    }


    @Override
    public FamilyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.family_list_item, parent, false);
        FamilyViewHolder pvh = new FamilyViewHolder(v);
        synchronized (holders) {
            holders.add(pvh);
        }
        return pvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FamilyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Family family = families.get(position);
        holder.setData(family);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return families.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (filter == null)
            filter = new FamilyFilter();
        return filter;
    }

    public static class FamilyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView personLname;
        public TextView timeLeft;
        public TextView visitors;
        public Family family;

        public FamilyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            personLname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_Lname);
            visitors = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.visitors);
            timeLeft = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_timeLeft);
        }

        public void setData(Family item) {
            family = item;
            personLname.setText(family.lastName);
            visitors.setText("מבקרים: "+ family.visitorsNum);
            updateFormatTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        }

        public void updateFormatTime(long currentMillis) {
            long timeLeft = family.time - currentMillis;
            int seconds = (int) (timeLeft / 1000) % 60;
            int minutes = (int) ((timeLeft / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
            if(seconds > 10 && minutes > 10)
                this.timeLeft.setText(minutes + ":" + seconds);
            else if(seconds > 10 && minutes < 10)
                this.timeLeft.setText("0" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
            else if (seconds < 10 && minutes > 10)
                this.timeLeft.setText(minutes + ":0" + seconds);
            else if (seconds < 10 && minutes < 10)
                this.timeLeft.setText("0" + minutes + ":0" + seconds);
        }
    }

    private class FamilyFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if(constraint.length() == 0 || constraint == null) {
                results.values = dataSet;
                results.count = dataSet.size();
                Log.d("Constraint is empty", "TRUE");
            } else {
                ArrayList<Family> queryResults = new ArrayList<Family>();
                for (Family f : dataSet) {
                    if (constraint.charAt(0) == f.lastName.toUpperCase().indexOf(0)){
                        queryResults.add(f);
                    }
                    else if (f.lastName.toUpperCase().contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
                        queryResults.add(f);
                    }
                }
                results.values = queryResults;
                results.count = queryResults.size();
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            // Now we have to inform the adapter about the new list filtered
            families = (ArrayList<Family>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public void stopThread() {
        tmr.cancel();
    }
}
```

Why the code is not working?

***UPDATE:*** Ok so I managed to solve this problem but simply put a CountDownTimer object in every ViewHolder who will work independently.

Now when the time is up, the background of the row item view and timer are changing perfectly

The problem is that when the first item's time is finished, the other rows are affected by this(their background is changed, but the timer still counts correcly).

Here is my adapter code now:

```
package bikurim.silverfix.com.bikurim.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import bikurim.silverfix.com.bikurim.Constants;
import bikurim.silverfix.com.bikurim.models.Family;
import bikurim.silverfix.com.bikurim.R;
import bikurim.silverfix.com.bikurim.utils.HolderListener;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.FamilyViewHolder> implements Filterable, HolderListener {

    // last position holds the last position of the element that was added, for animation purposes
    private int lastPosition = 0;
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Family> families;
    private ArrayList<Family> dataSet;
    private FamilyFilter filter;
    private boolean flagSearch;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Family> families) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dataSet = families;
        this.families = families;
    }


    @Override
    public FamilyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.family_list_item, parent, false);
        FamilyViewHolder pvh = new FamilyViewHolder(v, this);
        return pvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FamilyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Family family = families.get(position);
        holder.setData(family);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return families != null ? families.size() : 0;
    }


    /* The following 2 methods are an implementations of the HolderListener.
    * Inside every view holder lies an instance of HolderListener, for communication between the two*/

    @Override
    public void startAnimationOnItem(FamilyViewHolder holder) {
        setAnimation(holder.cardView, holder.getAdapterPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeEnds(Family family) {
        Toast.makeText(context, family.lastName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void removeData(int pos) {
        families.remove(pos);
        notifyItemRemoved(pos);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(pos, getItemCount());
    }
    public static class FamilyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public CardView cardView;
        public TextView personLname;
        public TextView timeLeft;
        public TextView visitors;
        public Family family;

        private CountDownTimer timer;
        private HolderListener listener;

        public FamilyViewHolder(View itemView, HolderListener listener) {
            super(itemView);
            this.listener = listener;
            cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            personLname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_Lname);
            visitors = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.visitors);
            timeLeft = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_timeLeft);
        }

        public void setData(Family item) {
            family = item;
            personLname.setText(family.lastName);
            visitors.setText("מבקרים: " + family.visitorsNum);
            setUpTimer();
        }

        public void setUpTimer() {
            long timeLeftInMillis =  family.time - System.currentTimeMillis();
            timer = new CountDownTimer(timeLeftInMillis, 1000) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    timeLeft.setText(updateFormatTime(millisUntilFinished));
                    family.time = System.currentTimeMillis() + millisUntilFinished;
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    notifyTimeEnd();
                    cancel();
                }
            };
            timer.start();
        }

        public void notifyTimeEnd() {
            family.isTimeLeft = true;
            timeLeft.setText("הזמן נגמר ");
            cardView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.time_up_bg);
            listener.startAnimationOnItem(this);
            listener.onTimeEnds(family);
        }
    }



/* Starts a slide in animation for a given Card View */
private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position) {
    if(position > lastPosition) {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
        viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
        lastPosition = position;
    }
}

    public static String updateFormatTime(long millisUntilFinished) {
        String result = "";
        int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60;
        int minutes = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
        if (seconds > 10 && minutes > 10)
            result = minutes + ":" + seconds;
        else if (seconds > 10 && minutes < 10)
            result = "0" + minutes +ing ":" + seconds;
        else if (seconds < 10 && minutes > 10)
            result = minutes + ":0" + seconds;
        else if (seconds < 10 && minutes < 10)
            result = "0" + minutes + ":0" + seconds;
        return result;
    }
}
```

In my activity, I have a ItemTouchHelper object for supporting a swipe-to-delete mechanism. Here is the code for this:

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback callback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                final int pos = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(FamilyListActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.confirmation_message)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.proceed_confirmation_dialog, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                adapter.removeData(pos);
                                String name = ((RecyclerViewAdapter.FamilyViewHolder) viewHolder).family.lastName;
                                Toast.makeText(FamilyListActivity.this, "משפחת "+name+" נמחקה מהרשימה", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }).setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_confirmation_dialog, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        adapter.notifyItemChanged(pos);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
        };
```

Why when one item deletes, it affects on all the other items in the list?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    public void updateFormatTime(long currentMillis) {
        long timeLeft = family.time - currentMillis;
        int seconds = (int) (timeLeft / 1000) % 60;
        int minutes = (int) ((timeLeft / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
        if(seconds > 10 && minutes > 10)
            this.timeLeft.setText(minutes + ":" + seconds);
        else if(seconds > 10 && minutes < 10)
            this.timeLeft.setText("0" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
        else if (seconds < 10 && minutes > 10)
            this.timeLeft.setText(minutes + ":0" + seconds);
        else if(seconds == 0 && minutes == 0)
            this.timeLeft.setText("Time is Over");
        else if (seconds < 10 && minutes < 10)
            this.timeLeft.setText("0" + minutes + ":0" + seconds);
    }
```

Comment: It's not what I'm looking for. Also the time will still count after the minutes and the seconds hit 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is unnecessarily over-complex but when you get to the update your `TextView` text use a simple ternary operator like this:

```
youTextView.setText(resultText.equals("00:00") ? "Time is over" : resultText);
```

Assume `resultText` String var is the result you get from your runnable.

Comment: But with what you are suggesting, the count down timer would still count the time. I'm trying to skip holders that were ended.

Comment: Well if the condition above is true you can stop your runnable, also you should check the "Date" class for easier human readable times.

Comment: How can I exactly stop the runnable if more view holders need to be checked? I'm not sure about it